# What does treating a method as a function mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

By assigning a variable (or value?) a method name with a space and an underscore, you tell scala to treat the method as a function, which apparently means doing more than simply taking the value generated by a call to the method and assigning to the variable.  What else is/can go on through such an assignment?

Comment: `foo _` is more like *package method foo into value*

Comment: possible duplicate of classic [Difference between method and function in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Answer (score 4):

Since Scala runs on the JVM, it's easier to understand in terms of simple Java-like classes without Scala's syntactic sugar.

Remember that Scala functions are essentially members of a class similar to the following (*signature deliberately simplified*):

```
class Function[X, Y] {
  def apply(x: X): Y
}
```

Application of a function `f` to an argument `x` is desugared into a method application `f.apply(x)`.

Now suppose that you have another class `Foo` with method `bar`:

```
class Foo {
  def bar(x: Int): String
}
```

If you now have an instance `foo` of type `Foo`, then whenever its method `bar` is transformed into a function by writing:

```
val f = foo.bar(_)
```

a new instance of an anonymous subclass of `Function` is created:

```
val f = new Function[Int, String] {
  def apply(x: Int) = foo.bar(x)
}
```

If you use this syntax inside a class, `this` is closed over instead of an instance `foo`.

This is what all those weirdly named classes `Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$1` are: they are the anonymous classes that represent functions. The functions can appear quite implicitly (for example, as blocks passed to the `for`-loops).

That's all there is to it semantically. The rest is just syntactic sugar.

Here is a complete runnable example that demonstrates the conversion of an instance method into a function:

1. with sugar, from the outside (a)
2. with sugar, from the inside (b)
3. without sugar, from the outside (c)
4. without sugar, from the inside (d)

You can save it into a file and execute with `scala <filename.scala>`:

```
/** A simple greeter that prints 'hello name' multiple times */
case class Hey(name: String) { thisHeyInst =>
  def hello(x: Int): String = ("hello " + name + " ") * x
  def withSugarFromInside = hello(_)
  def noSugarFromInside = new Function[Int, String] {
    def apply(y: Int) = thisHeyInst.hello(y)
  }
}

val heyAlice = Hey("Alice")
val heyBob = Hey("Bob")
val heyCharlie = Hey("Charlie")
val heyDonald = Hey("Donald")

val a = heyAlice.hello(_)
val b = heyBob.withSugarFromInside
val c = new Function[Int, String] { def apply(y: Int) = heyCharlie.hello(y) }
val d = heyDonald.noSugarFromInside

println(a(3))
println(b(3))
println(c(3))
println(d(3))
```

In all four cases, a greeting is printed three times.

Answer (score 1):

What `_` actually does is an [eta-conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion). It takes *compile-time* construction called method and returns *runtime* construction called anonymous function, which is actually an instance of scala's `Function`. Exactly the class depends on arity, so it might be [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1), Function2, Function3 and so on. The point here is to make [First-class citizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), which may act like a value.

OOP needs a little more than some new object. Before making the code that creates instance, compiler generates a new class (extending FunctionN) in compile-time, but theoretically it shouldn't be necessary a whole new class. For Java 8 it could be native [Java-lambdas](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat).

Btw, you may extend `Function1` by yourself and even eta-abstract it again:

```
 scala> object f extends (Int => Int) { def apply(a: Int) = a }
 scala> f(1)
 res0: Int = 1

 scala> f.apply _
 res1: Int => Int = <function1>

 scala> res1(5)
 res2: Int = 5
```

As a conclusion a little copy-paste from @Daniel C. Sobral's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/1809978):

> the former can be easily converted into the latter:
>
> ```
> val f = m _
> ```
>
> Scala will expand *that*, assuming `m` type is `(List[Int])AnyRef`
>   into (Scala 2.7):
>
> ```
> val f = new AnyRef with Function1[List[Int], AnyRef] {
>   def apply(x$1: List[Int]) = this.m(x$1)
> }
> ```
>
> On Scala 2.8, it actually uses an `AbstractFunction1` class to reduce
>   class sizes.

Or simply saying `val f = m _` is same as `val f = (x: List[Int]) => m(x)`

To make this answer more modern and precise let's see what's happening using `scalac` 2.11.2 and `javap`:

```
$ echo "object Z{def f(a: Int) = a}" > Z.scala //no eta-abstraction here

$ scalac Z.scala

$ ls
Z$.class    Z.class     Z.scala

$ echo "object Z{def f(a: Int) = a; val k = f _}" > Z.scala

$ scalac Z.scala

$ ls
Z$$anonfun$1.class  Z.class //new anonfun class added for lambda
Z$.class        Z.scala

$ javap -c Z\$\$anonfun\$1.class 
Compiled from "Z.scala" // I've simplified output a bit
public final class Z$$anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp implements scala.Serializable {

  public final int apply(int);
    Code:
      calling apply$mcII$sp(int)

  public int apply$mcII$sp(int); //that's it
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #25    // reading Field Z$.MODULE$:LZ$;, which points to `object Z`
       3: iload_1       
       4: invokevirtual #28    // calling Method Z$.f
       7: ireturn       

  public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object); //just boxed version of `apply`
    Code:

      unboxToInt
      calling apply(int) method
      boxToInteger       

  public Z$$anonfun$1();
    Code:
      AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp."<init>":()V //initialize

}
```

So it still extends `AbstractFunction1`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide some examples how a function or method are assigned to values with underscore.

If it's need to reference a zero-argument function

```
scala> val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID _
uuid: () => java.util.UUID = <function0>

scala> uuid()
res15: java.util.UUID = 3057ef51-8407-44c8-a09e-e2f4396f566e

scala> uuid()
uuid: java.util.UUID = c1e934e4-e722-4279-8a86-004fed8b9090
```

Check how it's different when one does

```
scala> val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID
uuid: java.util.UUID = 292708cb-14dc-4ace-a56b-4ed80d7ccfc7
```

In first case one assigned a reference to a function. And then calling uuid() generates new UUID every time.
In second, function `randomUUID` has been called and value assigned to a val `uuid`.

There are some other cases why _ might be useful. 
It's possible to use a function with two arguments and create a function with a single argument out of it.

```
scala> def multiply(n: Int)(m: Int) = n*m
multiply: (n: Int)(m: Int)Int

scala> val by2 = multiply(2) _
by2: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> by2(3)
res16: Int = 6
```

To be able to do, it's crucial to define function `multiply` as [curried](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala). It's called function currying.